# Unable to scrape the links of different albums from script tags using requests?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python together with selenium to get the links of different photo albums from a webpage. My script is parsing them flawlessly.

As the albums are public, no log-in is required.

Now, I wish to do the same using `requests` and `re` module as I can see the name of different albums in page source. However, most of the script tags are identical, so I can't scoop out the desired portion containing the required urls to the different albums.

[Website link](https://www.facebook.com/pg/bloo88/photos/?tab=albums)

Using selenium that works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/pg/bloo88/photos/?tab=albums'

def get_links(link):
    driver.get(link)
    items = sorted(set([item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[role='presentation'] > a")))]))
    return items 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
        for elem in get_links(url):
            print(elem)
```

While using `requests` and `re`, I'm getting lots of messy stuffs from which I can't dig out the desired links as most of the script tags are alike:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.facebook.com/pg/bloo88/photos/?tab=albums'

res = requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}).text
data = re.findall(r'adp_PagePhotosTabAlbums[^,]+(.*?)();</script>', res)[0]
print(data)
```

***How can I scrape the links of the different albums using requests?***

Comment: Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match your selenium output, which gives me 4 links, you can use the following regex. <sub>[try it](https://regex101.com/r/SXWarm/1)</sub>

```
import requests, re

base = 'https://www.facebook.com/pg/bloo88/photos/?tab=album&album_id='
p = re.compile(r'{"node":{"id":"(\d+)"')
r = requests.get('https://www.facebook.com/pg/bloo88/photos/?tab=albums')
links = [base + i for i in p.findall(r.text)]
```

Comment: It worked out just perfect!! Could you tell me how can I get the rest of the links? Much obliged.

Comment: I don’t think they are all present in the response. I think you need selenium and a slow scroll to grab all.